# Jquery cursor drag and release outside input detected as click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

Hi is there a way to prevent jquery from detecting a click event when you drag and release outside of an input field?
The thing is I have a modal window that closes when you click outside of the window (the backdrop). 
When you have an input field in the modal window and you select the text inside the input and drag your mouse all the way out of the modal window area, then release the click, the modal will close since it detects a click event on that element when it actually wasn't a click event but a "release" event.

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/imurphy/tafwzero/1/

Click event code:

```
$('.how').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  if(!$(e.target).is('.how')){
                return;
            }
    alert('Modal Closed');
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.You need use mousedown and mouseup handle the drag and drop

```
var isDragging = false;
    $(".how")
    .mousedown(function() {
        $(window).mousemove(function() {
            isDragging = true;
            $(window).unbind("mousemove");
        });
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        var wasDragging = isDragging;
        isDragging = false;
        $(window).unbind("mousemove");
        if (!wasDragging) {
            $(this).selection();
        }
    });


    $('.how').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  if(!$(e.target).is('.how')){
                return;
            }
    alert('Modal Closed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still getting the same results

Comment: are you using Bootstrap modal ? if yes just use static backdrop

`$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}) `

Comment: sorry but no, I am not using bootstrap's modal, I made a simple modal myself

Comment: Then make the backdrop static for you modal.

Comment: Sorry I can't, the default action is to click the backdrop to close the modal, it needs to be closed when you directly click the backdrop no when you release the click on it